# Losing SwaggerUI JWT Token when browser refreshed Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I use [DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger) to documentate my api.
I use Bearer JWT for authentication. When i create a new endpoint or make changes on existing one i need to refresh SwaggerUI page. Then i have to re-enter the token. How can i solve this?

I ve tried solutions on  [this issue](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/120) didn't work for me also.

This didn't work for me.

```
(function () {
const API_KEY = 'ApiKey';
setTimeout(function () {

  // store the api key in the local storage
  var originalAuthorize = ui.authActions.authorize;
  
  ui.authActions.authorize = function (payload) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(API_KEY, payload.ApiKeyScheme.value);
    return originalAuthorize(payload);
  };

  // if logout is clicked delete the api key in the local storage
  var originalLogout = ui.authActions.logout;

  ui.authActions.logout = function (payload) {
    window.localStorage.removeItem(API_KEY);
    return originalLogout(payload);
  };

  // If token already exists, load it from local storage
  const apiKey = window.localStorage.getItem(API_KEY);
  if (apiKey) {
    window.ui.preauthorizeApiKey('ApiKeyScheme', apiKey);
  }
}, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Just putting "**persistAuthorization: true**" to SwaggerUIBundle json solved my problem.

vendor\l5-swagger\index.blade.php

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
dom_id: '#swagger-ui',

url: "{!! $urlToDocs !!}",
operationsSorter: {!! isset($operationsSorter) ? '"' . $operationsSorter . '"' : 'null' !!},
configUrl: {!! isset($configUrl) ? '"' . $configUrl . '"' : 'null' !!},
validatorUrl: {!! isset($validatorUrl) ? '"' . $validatorUrl . '"' : 'null' !!},
oauth2RedirectUrl: "{{ route('l5-swagger.'.$documentation.'.oauth2_callback') }}",

requestInterceptor: function(request) {
  request.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
  return request;
},

presets: [
  SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
  SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
],

plugins: [
  SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
],

layout: "StandaloneLayout",

persistAuthorization: true,
})
```

You can find other needed parameters [here](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/).